# How to print out longest word in string WITHOUT using arrays and only loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

Currently, I am able to figure out how to display the longest word length. However, is there a way using loops to determine the longest word and also print it out?

```
    public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText)
{
    int lengthCounter = 0;
    int finalCounter = 0;
    int textLength = rawText.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < textLength ; i++)
    {
        String indexValue = Character.toString(rawText.charAt(i));
        if(!" ".equals(indexValue))
        {
            lengthCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            finalCounter = Math.max(finalCounter, lengthCounter);
            lengthCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final Value: " + Math.max(finalCounter, lengthCounter));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an solution without split:

```
public class LongestWord {

      public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText)
      {
          int lastSeparator = -1;
          int maxLength = 0;
          int solPosition = 0;
          int textLength = rawText.length();

          for (int i = 0; i < textLength ; i++)
          {
              //here you may check for other separators
              if (rawText.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                  lastSeparator = i; 
              }
              //assuming no separator is part of a word 
              else {
                  if (i - lastSeparator > maxLength) {
                      maxLength = i - lastSeparator;
                      solPosition = lastSeparator;
                  }
              }
          }
          if (maxLength > 0) {
              String solution = rawText.substring(solPosition+1, solPosition+maxLength+1);
              System.out.println("Longest word is: " + solution);
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("No solution finded!");
          }

      }

      public static void main (String args[]) {
          longestWordCalculator("la casa de mi amigo");
          longestWordCalculator("quiero agua");
          longestWordCalculator("bblablabla");
          longestWordCalculator("");
      }
}
```

Output:

```
Longest word is: amigo
Longest word is: quiero
Longest word is: bblablabla
No solution finded!
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution here is slick, and it will actually print out all the words with the longest length, instead of just one.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "one two three four five six seven eight nine";

        String currentWord = "";
        String largestWords = "";
        int longestLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

            char iteratedLetter = string.charAt(i);
            if (iteratedLetter == ' ') { // previous word just ended.

                if (currentWord.length() > longestLength) {
                    largestWords = "";
                    longestLength = currentWord.length();
                }
                else if (currentWord.length() == longestLength) {
                    largestWords += currentWord + " ";
                }

                currentWord = "";
            }
            else {
                currentWord += iteratedLetter;
            }



        }

        System.out.println("Largest words: " + largestWords);

    }
}
```

I encourage understanding the code though as you stated this is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Can use `split()` to split the string into a string array, then cycle through each element to check the length of the word. In this example, we're assuming there are no special characters and words are separated by white-space.

This function will find the first longest word, i.e. if there is a tie it will output the first word with the longest length. In the example below, you can see both `looking` and `longest` have the same number of characters, but it will only output `looking`.

```
public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText)
{
    int textLength = rawText.length();
    String longestWord = "";
    String[] words = rawText.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if (words[i].length() > longestWord.length()) {
          longestWord = words[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Longest word: " + longestWord);
    System.out.println("With length of: " + longestWord.length());
}
```

Usage:
`longestWordCalculator("Hello I am looking for the longest word");`

Outputs

> Longest word: looking
>
> With length of: 7

EDIT:

Without using arrays:

```
public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText)
{
    int nextSpaceIndex = rawText.indexOf(" ") + 1;
    String longestWord = "";
    do {
        String word = rawText.substring(0, nextSpaceIndex);
        rawText = rawText.substring(nextSpaceIndex); // trim string
        if (word.length() > longestWord.length()) {
            longestWord = word;
        }
        int tempNextIndex = rawText.indexOf(" ") + 1;
        nextSpaceIndex = tempNextIndex == 0 ? rawText.length() : tempNextIndex;
    } while (rawText.length() > 0);
    System.out.println("Longest word: " + longestWord);
    System.out.println("With length of: " + longestWord.length());
}
```

Comment: the assignment asks to not use arrays... is this possible? I was able to easily do it with arrays, but without is very head scratching

Comment: Yeah I am coding one using just a while loop and no arrays :)

Comment: Okay, please check edit. If people have helped you please remember to up-vote :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the text by space char and find the longest word. Try this code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText) {
        String[] words = rawText.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").split(" ");
        int foundIndex = -1;
        int maxLenght = 0;
        String foundWord = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (words[i].length() > maxLenght) {
                maxLenght = words[i].length();
                foundWord = words[i];
                foundIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Longest word is [Word=%s, WordLength=%s, WordIndex=%s]", foundWord, maxLenght, foundIndex));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        longestWordCalculator("It looks good");
    }
}
```

Input: "It looks good"

Output: Longest word is [Word=looks, WordLength=5, WordIndex=1]

Comment: the assignment asks to not use arrays... is this possible? I was able to easily do it with arrays, but without is very head scratching

Comment: I added another code. It keeps your implementation, not using array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and a `while` loop. Something like,

```
public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(rawText);
    String found = null;
    while (m.find()) {
        String s = m.group(1);
        if (found == null || s.length() > found.length()) {
            found = s;
        }
    }
    if (found == null) {
        System.out.println("No words found");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("The longest word in \"%s\" is %s which is %d characters.%n", 
                rawText, found, found.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The two answers posted are good and I would use them, however if you wanted to keep your current implementation and avoid arrays etc, you can save the location of the start of the current longest string when you save new longest length with `longestIndex = i - lengthCounter`. At the end, print out the substring in `rawText` from `longestIndex` to `longestIndex + finalCounter`.

Edit - try something like this

```
int lengthCounter = 0;
    int finalCounter = 0;
    int textLength = rawText.length();
    int longestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < textLength ; i++)
    {
        String indexValue = Character.toString(rawText.charAt(i));
        if(!" ".equals(indexValue))
        {
            lengthCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (lengthCounter > finalCounter) {
                longestIndex = i - lengthCounter;
                finalCounter = lengthCounter;
            }

            lengthCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final Value: " + finalCounter);
    System.out.println("Longest Word: " + rawText.substring(longestIndex, longestIndex + finalCounter));
```

Comment: how would that look like in my implementation?

Comment: @jimmyjohn123 I've edited my answer with some implementation. I didn't test it but it should be something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

I keep your code, not using array. Here is updated code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void longestWordCalculator(String rawText) {
        int lengthCounter = 0;
        int finalCounter = 0;
        int textLength = rawText.length();
        StringBuffer processingWord = new StringBuffer();
        String foundWord = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
            String indexValue = Character.toString(rawText.charAt(i));
            if (!" ".equals(indexValue)) {
                processingWord.append(rawText.charAt(i));
                lengthCounter++;

            } else {
                if (finalCounter < lengthCounter) {
                    finalCounter = lengthCounter;
                    foundWord = processingWord.toString();
                    processingWord = new StringBuffer();
                }
                lengthCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final Value: " + finalCounter + ", Word: " + foundWord);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        longestWordCalculator("It looks good");
    }
}
```

Hope it can help.